# Structural breaks and residuals analysis for ARIMA models

Tags: time-series, arima, residuals, normality-assumption, structural-change

I have two question regarding ARIMA modeling.

1) When I work with ARIMA models should I test for the absence of structural breaks? If the answer is yes, what function of R could I use to detect a structural break and eventually fix it?

2) Since an ARIMA model takes into account autocorrelation in a time series, and that heteroscedasticity can be embedded via arch/garch, what are the consequences of non-normality of residuals over an ARIMA model (with log-transformed data that follow heavy tails distribution) and solutions to the problem (preferably via the software R)?

Comment: I think the second question has been discussed in several earlier threads; you may search the site using the relevant keywords and tags. You may start [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=non-normal+arima).

Comment: Unfortunately those topics are not very usefull from a mere operational point of view and the question of structural breaks hasn't find a Solution...